2GP dependent package creation fails with dependency error
We have a 2GP devhub in which we are trying to create packages.
Our main package has a released version, and this main package is a dependency for our other package in the same namespace.
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "Base",
      "default": true,
      "package": "SomeName",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "versionDescription": "",
      "ancestorVersion": "HIGHEST"
    },
    {
      "path": "Sub",
      "package": "SubName",
      "versionName": "Beta 1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": false,
      "versionDescription": "",
      "dependencies": 
        [ 
          {
            "package": "SomeName",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.4"
          }
        ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "name",
  "namespace": "namespaceName",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "59.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "SomeName": "0Hoxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "SubName": "0Hoxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}

Now I'm trying to create a beta version of the Sub package with the command:
sf package version create --package SubName --installation-key XXXXXXXXXXX -c

But this returns an error:
Warning: (1) An error occurred while trying to install a package dependency, ID 04tzzzzzzzzzzzz: null

Where the 04tzzzzzzzzzzzzzz key is the same as the Subscriber Package Version ID of version 0.1.0.4 of the base package (minus the last 3 characters, so the Subscriber Package version ID is 04tzzzzzzzzzzzzAA2.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong or what is missing for this to fail? Already tried 4 times so my Package2VersionCreates limit for today is almost up (So hatefull that a failed version counts toward the limits...)

Have you tried to enable CLI debug logging to see if there is any detail around the error?

No I havent, I tried doing so with the info found at link but I get an error. How do I enable this correctly?

What error did you get? You might also try --verbose as a flag on the command.

if I do 'sf export SF_LOG_LEVEL=debug' and then choose
'data export tree'
I get 'Try the the new "sf data export beta tree" command.  It support SOQL queries with up to 5 levels of objects!
Error (2): Unexpected argument: SF_LOG_LEVEL=debug

You need to set the environment variable using your OS's command line or UI, not as an argument to the CLI itself. E.g. export SF_LOG_LEVEL=debug as one command then sf package version create --package SubName --installation-key XXXXXXXXXXX -c as another. If using Windows, use the Control Panel or similar to set the environment variables you want.

Now I get this error ModuleLoadError: [MODULE_NOT_FOUND] require failed to load   »   C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\sf\node_modules\@salesforce\plugin-packaging\lib\commands\package\version\create.js: Cannot find module 'glob'

I tried npm install -g glob but the error remains

OK, so that makes it sound like you have a CLI installation issue. Perhaps you should uninstall it and reinstall from scratch. You might also like to search for issues on the CLI issue tracker.

I unintstalled the CLI, reinstalled it using npm, tried to create a new package, but now I still get the Warning: (1) An error occurred while trying to install a package dependency, ID 04XXXXXXXXXXXXX: null error but no longer do I get the extended error tekst, although the environmental variable is still set...

Not sure what else to suggest, sorry. You need to get the error detail somehow because without it you won't have the information needed to find a resolution. You might need to raise a Salesforce Support case.
